# Finding and obtaining the difference between two columns

Tags: excel, difference

I have two columns. Each column has tens of thousands of values. I need to find the difference between them and print the difference in some cells. I read similar questions, but they are not enough for my question, highlighting the different cells is not enogh for me because it would be very tiring to look at tens of thousands of cell by searching highlighted cells. Thus, i need to obtain the values.

Example:

Column1     Column2

John        Jennifer

Mary        Washington

Joe         John

Michael     Texas

Houston     Newyork

Texas       Mary

Values existing in col1 but not col2 : Joe, Michael, Houston

Values existing in col1 but not col2 : Jennifer, Washington, New York

Algorithmically, i need to check each row of column1 whether it exists in Column2, if the row does not exist in Column2, the value is taken.

Similarly,   i need to check each row of column2 whether it exists in Column1, if the row does not exist in Column1, the value is taken.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old: *If this is a once-off i'd make a backup then mark the area of the two columns and "remove duplicates" which is a button on the DATA command bar.
You would be left with unique records only, which is what I understand you want.*

Edit: If you want to completely remove duplicate values then: Assuming that col1 is "A" and col2 is "B" then this formula only shows the record if it is in A but not in B. You can make a similar one for B not in A. In my example I made two columns C, D for the unique values. Then filter the list on these being "not nothing", and you have a set of unique records.

Current formula is for A2 cell - in my example placed in C2.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2;B:B;0));A2;"")
```

Comment: No, if a value has a duplicate, i want to delete both value from two columns.